# A $q$-analogue of Foulkes' character related to alternating permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-groups, q-analogs

My paper "Alternating permutations and symmetric functions" at
http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/altenum.pdf enumerates certain
classes of alternating permutations, such as those whose inverse is
alternating or which have a given cycle type. The key result on which
the proofs depend is that for a certain (reducible) character $\chi$
of the symmetric group $S_n$ the character values are all either 0 or
$\pm E_k$, where $E_k$ is an Euler number (the number of alternating
permutations of $1,2,\dots,k$). This character was first considered by
Foulkes. (For the cognoscenti, it is the character corresponding to a
ribbon staircase.) I am interested in whether there are $q$-analogues
of my results, e.g., enumerating the various classes of permutations
by some statistic such as major index or number of inversions. A
natural approach would be to find a $q$-analogue of Foulkes' character
$\chi$. Some first attempts such as the Hall-Littlewood or Hecke
algebra analogues of the characters of $S_n$ don't seem to work.

Comment: There is a way to define q-Bernoulli numbers using a q-analog of the usual Bernoulli umbra (see the works of Carlitz on q-Bernoulli numbers). Maybe something similar could work for the Euler umbra you are using ?